# Apache Tomcat 5.5.23 error. HTTP Status 500

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Following is the stack trace

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(jasper5-compiler-5.5.23.jar.so)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(tomcat5-servlet-2.4-api-5.5.23.jar.so)
```

Comment: There is most likely a caused-by exception - ie, the original problem with caused this exception: please include the full stacktrace which will include this information

Comment: You can see full stack trace at http://118.139.162.5:8080/waveteleVTS/dashboard_new.jsp

Comment: In the future, please copypaste the stacktrace straight in the question. Do not link to an external resource which disappears with time which in turn makes your question completely worthless and too localized in Stackoverflow knowledge base. I will remove my downvote if you edit the question and copypaste the original full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this code is compiled pre generics support,

```
An error occurred at line: 236 in the jsp file: /dashboard_new.jsp
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
```

recompile the code with jdk >= 1.5 would be my guess or maybe the tomcat server is setup to use a jdk < 1.5

hope that helps

EDIT:

all of the errors apart from the one below seem to be a compiled version issue.

this one :

```
An error occurred at line: 338 in the jsp file: /dashboard_new.jsp
Incompatible conditional operand types String and int
335: out.println( "<td valign=\"top\">" +      frameBean.getLatitude() + "</td>" );
336: out.println( "<td valign=\"top\">" + frameBean.getLongitude() + "</td>" );
```

seems to be  trying to concatonate Strings and Integers.  this should also work in later versions of java, i think.

Comment: What about the remaining errors?

Comment: One error at a time, please. Very often all subsequent errors will instantly disappear or change to something entirely different when you fix the first one.

Comment: i was in a helpful mood so had a crack at the other issues, as BalusC says though these error may go when you fix the others.